# Using VoiceProcessingIO along with AUSampler

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, audiounit

I'm  trying to implement something similar to flute that when you blow the mic it's going to start play one note from the speaker. For this reason I was trying to use `VoiceProcessingIO` to substract playbacked note (output speaker) from input mic.

For some reason I noticed `VoiceProcessingIO` doesn't work together with `AUSampler`. I modified Apple Sampled "*LoadPresetDemo*" and just changed line:

```
cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO
```

with

```
cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO;
```

and then you cannot hear anything played

I had the same effect (no sound) when I used the following scheme of audiounits:

```
VoiceProcessingIO (input mic) --> processing function (if audio level > thrs 
                                              then feed MusicDeviceMIDIEvent)

AUSampler --> VoiceProcessingIO (output speaker)
```

However when I used the scheme below:

```
VoiceProcessingIO (input mic) --> processing function (if audio level > thrs 
                                              then feed MusicDeviceMIDIEvent)

AUSampler --> RemoteIO (output speaker)
```

The output speaker volume was much lowered. The issue It seams is related to this:
[Is it safe to use two audio units for simultaneous I/O in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702329/is-it-safe-to-use-two-audio-units-for-simultaneous-i-o-in-ios)

I've tested also example from here:
https://code.google.com/p/ios-coreaudio-example/downloads/detail?name=Aruts.zip&can=2&q=

And it works with the following scheme without AUSampler:

```
VoiceProcessingIO (input mic) --> processing function --> VoiceProcessingIO (output speaker)
```

**Questions is:**

Is there any way to use `VoiceProcessingIO` along with `AUSampler`? Or is the only way to feed some data to
`VoiceProcessing` output via render callback?